# How can I access a ruby integer's sign bit?

Tags: ruby, bit-manipulation

I would like to access a ruby integer's sign bit directly.

Ruby allows access to an int's bits through the `[]` operator:

`1[0] -> 1
2[1] -> 1`

I tried `-1[-1]` (to access the last one), but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can understand this by looking at the documentation for `Fixnum#[]` :

> Returns the +n+th bit in the binary representation of fix, where fix[0] is the least significant bit

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-5B-5D

A `Fixnum` is not an array, thus its `#[]` function can (and does) behave differently to what you'd expect from an array.

## Solution 1

To access the most significant bit you can use `#bit_length - 1`

```
> a = 5
=> 5
> a[a.bit_length - 1]
=> 1
```

However, **this excludes the sign bit for negative numbers**, so to get the sign bit, do not remove 1 from the `bit_length`

```
> a = -5
=> 5
> a[a.bit_length]
=> 1
> a = 42
=> 42
> a[a.bit_length]
=> 0
```

## Solution 2

You could also just use a `< 0` comparison:

```
> a = -5
=> -5
> sign_bit = a < 0 ? 1 : 0
=> 1
```

## Solution 3

First of all, let's read the documentation for `#size`:

> Returns the number of bytes in the machine representation of fix.

From the implementation of the function we can gather that if the stored number is inside the bounds of a 32-bit signed integer if will be stored in one. In this case `#size` returns `4`. If it is larger it will be stored in a 64-bit integer and `#size` will return `8`.

However not all of these bits are in use. If you store the number `5` (0b101) your 32 bits will be occupied as such

```
10100000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Negative numbers are most of the time stored as the 2s complement (not sure if applicable for ruby) which would mean that if you store the number `-5` your 32 bits will be occupied as such

```
11011111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

Thus you can also access the sign bit with the following code:

```
x[x.size * 8 - 1]
```

---

## Bonus

If you're curious about why `5[-1]` does not throw an exception and still returns a number, you can look at the source code for `Fixnum#[]` (on the documentation page previously mentioned).

```
if (i < 0) return INT2FIX(0);
```

It is made to just return `0` if your index is a negative number.

Comment: So a[a.bit_length -1] returns 1 for a = 5. It should be 0. But a[a.size] seems to work well. Thanks for a pointer in the right direction!

Comment: Edited my answer because I realised a downfall of `bit_length`. Don't use `size`, it gives you the amount of bytes used to represent your number. it is entirely coincidental that you get the right result, try it with `-17999` rather than `5` and you'll see

Comment: @zimkies Since `size` gives the number of bytes, a simple variant of your comment seems to work:  `a[a.size * 8 - 1]`

Comment: Your solution will work as long as you are certain that negative numbers are stored as their 2s complement in ruby (or at least on the platform you're targetting)

Comment: Ah, yes, size is wrong. But `a[a.bit_length + 1]` seems to be the most efficient answer.